# set empty text inputs to zero with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is basic stuff but I'd like any text input that's left blank to have a value of zero so it can still be included in a function and not mess with the final sum of the equation.

At the moment I'm just setting `<input type="text" id="id" value="0">` since nothing will be divided by a `var value = document.getElementById("id");` but I don't want to see the zeros in the text boxes.

Is there an better way to not include empty inputs in an equation?

Comment: You can use `placeholder` attribute. `<input type="text" id="id" placeholder="0">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `||` operator along with a default value to exclude empty text boxes (or none existent ones) all in one line:

```
var value = document.getElementById("id").value || "0";
```

Or, if you want an integer value (since it looks like you're going to do calculations):

```
var value = +document.getElementById("id").value || 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, new to this stuff but it seems like doing it this way lets me exclude `parseFloat()` and I'm not hating that.

Answer (score 0):

Dont set the value on the input. Don't use a placeholder either it will show in the input.

```
var value = document.getElementById("id").value;

if (value !== "") {
    //use it here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're searching for a numeric value to be used in a equation, you can just do all the calculations internally to avoid displaying those values in the inputs, for example:

```
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("id"));

if(isNaN(value)){
    value = 0;
}
```

You just first parse the result to int (or float, any type that works for you), then you verify if it's a valid number, and if not, then you just assign it a value of zero. That way you can use it in your equation and you will not need to display that zero in the input.